# RabbitMQ basic.get and acknowledgement

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit, spring-amqp

I'm invoking:

```
GetResponse response = channel.basicGet("some.queue", false); // no auto-ack
....
channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, ...);
```

However, when I invoke `basicGet`, the messages in the queue stay in "Ready", rather than in "Unacknowledged". I want them to be in unacknowledged, so that I can either `basic.ack` them (thus discarding them from the queue), or `basic.nack` them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing `ack` immediately after the `get` it works fine. However, in my case, they were separated by a request. And spring's template closes the channel and connection on each execution. So there are three options:

- keep one channel and connection open throughout the whole lifetime of the application
- have some kind of conversation-scope (or worst-case: use the session) to store the same channel and reuse it.
- use one channel per request, acknowledge receipt immediately, and store the messages in memory.

In the former two cases you can't do it with spring's `RabbitTemplate`

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing the following to mimic **Delaying the ack**:

#### At consumption time

1. Get(consume) the message form the initial Queue.
2. Create a "PendingAck_123456" Queue.
   123456 is a unique id of the message.
   Set the following properties

   - *x-message-ttl* (to requeue after
     timeout)
   - *x-expires* (to make sure the temp queue will be deleted)
   - *x-dead-letter-exchange* and *x-deal-letter-routing-key* to **requeue to
     the initial Queue upon TTL expiration**.
3. Publish the message Pending ack to this "PendingAck_123456" Queue
4. Ack the message to delete it from the initial queue

#### At Acknowledge time

1. Calculate Queue Name from Message Id and Get from the "PendingAck_123456" Queue
2. Acknowledge it (no need to call `.getBody()` ).
   That'll delete it from this pending queue, preventing the TTL to requeue it

#### Remarks

- A Queue for only 1 message.. Is that an issue if there are *a lot* of such Queues ?
- A requeued message will be sent at the queue input side.. not at the queue output (as would do a real ack).. There is an impact on the messages order.
- Message is copied by the application to the Pending Queue.. This is an additional step that may have impacts on the overall performance.
- To mimic a Nack/Reject, you you may want to Copy the message to the Initial Queue, and Ack it from the PendingAck queue. By default, the TTL would do it (later).

Answer (score 0):

```
GetResponse resp = channel.basicGet(queueName, false);
Envelope envelope = resp.getEnvelope();
long deliveryTag = envelope.getDeliveryTag();
channel.basicAck(deveryTag,false)
```