# .Net RabbitMQ client Subscriber.Next hangs

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using RabbitMQ .net client in a windows service.  I have millions of messages coming in bulk which then get processed and then the output is put on another queue. I am creating the connection factory with a heartbeat of 30 and then creating a connection whenever a connection or subscriber is lost.  In production, my code *probably* works in most cases.  However, in my integration tests, I know it is failing most of the time. Here is my code:

```
public void ReceiveAll(Func<IDictionary<ulong, byte[]>, IOnStreamWatchResult> onReceiveAllCallback, int batchSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    IModel channel = null;
    Subscription subscription = null;

    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (subscription == null || subscription.Model.IsClosed)
        {
            channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel(ref _connection, _messageQueueConfig, _connectionFactory);
            // This instructs the channel to not prefetch more than batch count into shared queue
            channel.BasicQos(0, Convert.ToUInt16(batchSize), false);
            subscription = new Subscription(channel, _messageQueueConfig.Queue, false);
        }

        try
        {
            BasicDeliverEventArgs message;
            var dequeuedMessages = new Dictionary<ulong, byte[]>();
            do
            {
                if (subscription.Next(_messageQueueConfig.DequeueTimeout.Milliseconds, out message))
                {
                    if (message == null)
                    {
                        // This means channel is closed and the messages in shared queue would get moved back to ready state
                        DisposeChannelAndSubcription(ref channel, ref subscription);
                        ReceiveAll(onReceiveAllCallback, batchSize, cancellationToken);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dequeuedMessages.Add(message.DeliveryTag, message.Body);
                    }
                }
            } while (message != null && batchSize > dequeuedMessages.Count && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested);

            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                if (dequeuedMessages.Any())
                {
                    NackUnProcessedMessages(subscription, dequeuedMessages.Keys);
                }
                DisposeChannelAndSubcription(ref channel, ref subscription);
                dequeuedMessages.Clear();
                break;
            }

            try
            {
                var onStreamWatchResult = onReceiveAllCallback(dequeuedMessages);
                AckProcessedMessages(subscription, onStreamWatchResult.Processed);
                NackUnProcessedMessages(subscription, onStreamWatchResult.UnProcessed);
                dequeuedMessages.Clear();
            }
            catch(Exception unhandledException)
            {
                NackUnProcessedMessages(subscription, dequeuedMessages.Keys);
            }
        }
        catch (EndOfStreamException endOfStreamException)
        {
            DisposeChannelAndSubcription(ref channel, ref subscription);
        }
        catch (OperationInterruptedException operationInterruptedException)
        {
            DisposeChannelAndSubcription(ref channel, ref subscription);
        }
    }
}
```

The batch size is set to 4 because I put 4 messages in my integration test, which is just a windows service that I ran after running unit tests.

The issue here is that almost always, the subscriber pre-fetches 4 messages, as expected, returns true for the first two .Next iterations, but after that it returns false.  I believe that is happening because my messages are not getting unacked properly.  In my integration test, I ack 2 and nack 2 messages and then read the 2 nacked messages again to clear the queue.  However, after nacking, the messages are not returned to ready state and hence the test hangs.  What am I doing wrong here? Am I not understanding something from the nacking documentation?  Here is my nacking code:

```
subscription.Model.BasicNack(deliveryTag, false, true);
```

Comment: I tried Subscription.Nack method and changed code to use BasicDeliverEventArgs instead of just the ulong message id.  Still no effect. After nacking, the messages remain in unacked state and are not getting requeued until everything is disposed. Is there a flush command I can use?

Comment: Found two posts with similar issues.  I cannot set the prefetch to 1 because that will significantly degrade the performance of my app. I am already having enough issues grabbing XML data from SQL server and putting it in queues. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7849891/1896364 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/21244281/1896364